# kvm solution to connect 2 monitor, keyboard and mouse in 2 different rooms?

Tags: networking

I have a workshop in my backyard, and it is an unfriendly place to position a computer; so I was wondering if there is a product on the market, that would allow me to control the computer in the house.

A KVM is uses to connect one monitor, keyboard and mouse to different computers; while I need something that does the opposite: I need a way to connect 1 computer to 2 monitor, 2 keyboard and 2 mouse (one at my desk in the house, one in the workshop in the backyard).

Is there anything like this? IF yes, what is the proper name? I was thinking to use a raspberry PI and use it to connect via network using remote desktop, but it is incredibly slow and inefficient

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your mouse and keyboard are USB and your monitor is HDMI, you could just attach those directly using range extenders for USB and HDMI. Range extenders usually connect using ethernet cable.

Another, in my view better alternative is to install a thin client (faster than the Raspberry, of course) or small format PC and connect via Remote Desktop or some other remote view technology such as VNC.

Comment: I did try to look for extenders, but I found only extenders for HDMI; thye do not have also usb ports to connect a keyboard and mouse; so even if I can receive the signal in the other room; there is no way for me to control the computer. VNC is not really feasible; tried it and it didn't cut. Not sure if it is because of the raspberry, but that's what I have....I don't mind waste 40 dollars for the raspberry, but I can't spend 200 or more for a small factor pc, since I work with wood and stone; so particles fly all over and that's the main reason for not getting a computer there in first place